# Building hierarchy using Spark

Tags: apache-spark

Imagine I've got such a tree:

```
- One
  - One one
  - One two
    - One two one
    - One two two
    - One two three
      - One two three one
  - One three
    - One three one
    - One three two
    - One three three
  - One four
  - One five
```

Data wise it's quite simple too, just a child-parent relationship:

```
+-------------------+---------------+
|       Child       |    Parent     |
+-------------------+---------------+
| One               |               |
| One one           | One           |
| One two           | One           |
| One two one       | One two       |
| One two two       | One two       |
| One two three     | One two       |
| One two three one | One two three |
| One three         | One           |
| One three one     | One three     |
| One three two     | One three     |
| One three three   | One three     |
| One four          | One           |
| One five          | One           |
+-------------------+---------------+
```

Now what I'd like to do is:

- I've got a list of two items, let's say `One three three` and `One two three one`
- I'd like to build rest of tree parents to the root level

In a RDBMS, I'd simply write a recursive query using CTE and UNION ALL, however I cannot find whether that's possible in Spark using Dataset or DataFrame, probably due to lack of Scala/Python knowledge. Any help would be appreciated.

Output should be as follows:

```
- One
  - One two
    - One two three
      - One two three one
  - One three
    - One three three
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Graphx-based solution to perform a recursive query (parent/child or hierarchical queries) . This is a functionality provided by many databases called Recursive Common Table Expressions (CTE) or Connect by SQL Clause

See this article for more information: https://www.qubole.com/blog/processing-hierarchical-data-using-spark-graphx-pregel-api/

Comment: I am very familiar with cte approach and was looking for equivalent in spark. I'll check it out, thanks!